# error -The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am trying to build the android apk. I am facing the below error.

Tried with flutter clean, updated pub get, and I am using flutter 2.2.3

The build failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetifier to solve the incompatibility.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
Running Gradle task 'assembleAarRelease'...

Comment: Add some more details on the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Do these steps : 1. Try adding this line In your Project folder > android > app > build.gradle, add the following Line in

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

inside defaultConfig

2.Then upgrade `gradle` dependency in the `android/build.gradle` file: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' (previously on version 3.2.1)

3.Run flutter clean and rebuild your project

Comment: As you said above I have already these changes but I am facing and I find an error "JSON schema error" and it's not allowing me to create the .apk bundle. I am using Flutter 2.3.3

Answer (score 0):

Based on your other feedback, the basic troubleshooting is
(1) flutter doctor and
(2) to try to build the apk for the sample app. See https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/test-drive?tab=terminal

If the build works with the sample app, then you know your environment is good but something is up with your app.

(3) if you think your gradle might be corrupted, you might copy your `lib/` and `pubspec.yaml` to a blank project to start.

You mentioned a cloud_firestore issue. There are several things that need to be setup to get cluod_firestore working, including the `google-services.json` that are easy to mess up.

You might also have version incompatabilities with firebase. There are some breaking changes in the last couple of years.

I always try to run the sample/example code first to see if my tooling is correct. So, try that with flutter fire: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview